# ASP.NET Core Blazor Web Application publishing problems

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, web-applications, blazor

Me and a colleague recently completed our website for making journal-entries and noting school grades. We made the website using ASP.NET Core and Blazor. When launching in Visual Studio, there are no errors and everything works fine.
We then published the website into a single-file-executable and uploaded said file to the server. On the server we then installed Nginx. We then made sure to redirect to the correct port (Port 5000).
Now as soon as I start the executable file, everything seems to run fine at first:

```
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/home/admin/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/FHNW_ASS
```

But as soon as I want to access the website from my browser, the following happens:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://server0070.cs.technik.fhnw.ch/  
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsValidationException: The 'Instance' option must be provided.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]
      An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsValidationException: The 'Instance' option must be provided.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM4FGBOGTTSI", Request id "0HM4FGBOGTTSI:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsValidationException: The 'Instance' option must be provided.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 79.4377ms 500
```

Here is the Startup.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FHNW_ASS.Helpers;
using FHNW_ASS.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;
using Blazored.Modal;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using FHNW_ASS.Services;

namespace FHNW_ASS
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }


        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddBlazoredModal();
            services.AddTransient<IJournalService, JournalService>();
            services.AddTransient<IGradeService , GradeService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddTransient<ICascadingDropdownService, CascadingDropdownService>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(options => this.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            var appSetingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSetingsSection);
            var appSettings = appSetingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();

            services.AddDbContext<FHNW_ASSContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseMySql(appSettings.SqlConnectionString, mysqlOptions =>
                {
                    mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(10, 1, 39), ServerType.MySql);
                });
            }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here the appsettings.json (I obviously took away the ClientID, TenantID, username and password for security reasons):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlConnectionString": "Server=10.35.146.70;Port=64141;database=FHNW_ASS;user id=;password="
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "fhnw.ch",
    "TenantId": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "appSettings": {
    "SqlConnectionString": "Server=10.35.146.70;Port=64141;database=FHNW_ASS;user id=;password="
  },
  "Urls": { 
    "Urls": "http://localhost:64141"
  }
}
```

And here is the launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:62653",
      "sslPort": 44397
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "FHNW_ASS": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      //"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you are going to be able to help me, let me know when you need any additional information and I'll see if I can provide it!

Comment: I think you need to check this github issue:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13311

Comment: I was able to fix the Issue. The problem was, that my appsettings-file wasn't read from for some reason. So what I did was the following:
I replaced this line of Code
`services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(options => this.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));`

Comment: With this one, to force the program to use the right options:
`services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddAzureAD(options => {
                options.ClientId = "";
                options.TenantId = "";
                options.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
                options.Domain = "fhnw.ch";
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
               });`

I obviously blanked out ClientId and TenantId for privacy and security.